# Как динамически обновлять JSF страницу?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, java-ee, jsf

Есть Бд оттуда принимаются данные на Jsf но когда в бд записывается запись из утсровта то Jsf страницу надо обнавть чтоб там отобразились изменеия не моглиб вы мне помоч разобраться с этим ,узнал что есть спец скрипты для этого Ajax но их много и какой где как использовать незнаю

вот моя разметка

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:link outcome="create" value="Insert a new employee"/>
        <h:form>
            <h:dataTable value="#{empControl.lst}" var="em">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name ="header">ID</f:facet>
                    #{em.id}
                </h:column>
                 <h:column>
                    <f:facet name ="header">Name</f:facet>
                    #{em.name}
                </h:column>
                 <h:column>
                    <f:facet name ="header">Address</f:facet>
                    #{em.addr}
                </h:column>
                 <h:column>
                    <f:facet name ="header">Email</f:facet>
                    #{em.email}
                </h:column>
                 <h:column>
                    <f:facet name ="header">Phone</f:facet>
                    #{em.phone}
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Actions</f:facet>
                    <h:commandLink value="Remove" action="#{empControl.remove(em)}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure')"></h:commandLink>
                    <h:commandButton value ="Edit"
                                     action="#{empControl.edit(em)}"></h:commandButton>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
            </h:form>
        </h:body>
</html>
```

как сделать чтоб она обновялась как в бд чтото добавят и сразу отображала а ненадо было обновть страницу .Спасибо благодарю за помощ.

> П.С за свой Русский прошу прошения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов решения задачи.

1. Периодический опрос сервера на наличие изменений данных. Например, в `Primefaces`, это можно сделать с помощью компонента [poll](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/poll.xhtml). Этот подход наиболее прост в реализации, но решает задачу не самым эффективным образом - информационный обмен между клиентом и сервером будет происходить независимо от того, изменились данные или нет, что вызовет дополнительную нагрузку. Тем не менее, **я бы рекомендовал использовать именно этот вариант** для быстрой реализации задачи, т.к. не следует делать преждевременную оптимизацию функции, неэффективность которой не доказана тестами или промышленной эксплуатацией. Если впоследствии окажется, что нагрузка слишком высокая - то можно перейти к варианту 2.
2. Использование *сокетов*. Это более правильный вариант с точки зрения эффективности использования ресурсов. Но при этом и более сложный в реализации. Могу предложить 2 направления для изучения этой темы:

   а) Использование `Javascript` и спецификаций `Java EE`, без каких-то специфических компонентов. Пример есть [здесь](http://dreamand.me/java/jee7-websocket-example/). Это простое приложения чата. Можно приспособить его под Вашу задачу - когда происходит событие добавления записи в таблицу, на страницу отправляется сообщение. В Вашем случае, вместо обновления компонента чата, должно вызываться обновление `dataTable`. Для варианта а) потребуется развернуть ваше приложение под управлением сервера приложений, реализующего спецификацию `JEE 7 Web profile`, например - `Wildfly 10`. Альтернативный вариант - подключение вручную требующихся компонентов в ваше приложение (не рекомендую, можно потерять немало времени на этом).

   б) Использование компонента фреймворка `Primefaces` [Notify](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml). Общий принцип работы компонента такой же, что в варианте а), но данный вариант может более гармонично вписаться на `JSF`-страницу.

PS Если решили писать `JSF`-приложение, настоятельно рекомендую использовать `Primefaces` - там реализовано огромное количество типовых компонентов и функций, которых достаточно для разработки большинства типов приложений.

Comment: Здраствйте спасибо что откликнулись .Хорошо щас буду копаться в сторону primeFaces. большое спасибо за указатели!

Comment: У меня серв 96 гб как думаете еслт с poll делать вытерпит:

Comment: 96Гб чего? Зависит от количества одновременно подключенных пользователей и от частоты обновления. У меня сервер с 1 Гб ОЗУ и процессором 1 ГГц выдерживал 20 запросов в секунду. Но тут сильно зависит от того, насколько "тяжёлые" действия будут выполняться сервером в ответ на запрос. Если сделать интервал между запросами 5 секунд, до 20 запросов в секунду - это 100 одновременно подключенных пользователей.